# How do I switch Flash players?

Tags: 11.04, firefox, flash, adobe, gnash

Firefox shows that I've got Gnash installed, but in Synaptic I have the most recent Adobe Flashplayer. I've been having trouble with Flash content not working, and I'd like to try switching to the Adobe player. I can't figure out how to do that, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First make sure you have the `flashplugin-installer` package installed.  Afterwards, you should be able to select your preferred alternative for the plugin by running the following commands:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config firefox-flashplugin
sudo update-alternatives --config mozilla-flashplugin
```

If either command prompts you an option, pick the one you prefer.